# How to submit row from one table to another using php, msqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php search script.

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM florinvtable
            WHERE (`Brand` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Category` LIKE '%".$query."%')
            ORDER BY Category, Brand, Price") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<div style='position:relative; font-size:18px; width:500px;'><span style='font-size:14px'>".$results['Category']."</span> - <strong>".$results['Brand']."</strong> - ".$results['Description']." - <span style='color:red;'>$".$results['Price']."</span> ".$results['Size']."</div>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

I would like to incorporate a submit button for each row displayed that I can click on to copy a row to an identical separate table. You might ask, why maintain two identical tables? The answer is the original table is frequently truncated. That said, how would I incorporate a submit button into the above script using the script below.

```
<?php    

$query = "INSERT INTO floradtable (Category, Brand, Price) 
          SELECT Category, Brand, Price FROM florinvtable 
          WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."' 
          LIMIT 0,1";

$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

As a side note, I know I am mixing mysql with mysqli which I will address after I work out a solution for the current problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Thanks for the slap in the face. I needed that. So now that I'm thinking, I guess I should include a form & submit button in the echo statement that access the latter script in a separate .php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.

```
   if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
        $query = "INSERT INTO floradtable (Category, Brand, Price) VALUES";
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
            $query .=  "('".$results['Category']."','".$results['Brand']."','".$results['Price']."'),";
            echo "<div style='position:relative; font-size:18px; width:500px;'><span style='font-size:14px'>".$results['Category']."</span> - <strong>".$results['Brand']."</strong> - ".$results['Description']." - <span style='color:red;'>$".$results['Price']."</span> ".$results['Size']."</div>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }
        $query = substr($query, 0, -1);//to remove the trailing comma
        $mysqli->query($query);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Abhihek - looks like the answer you provided inserts results into table without any action required on my part other than doing the search. However, I want to select specific rows from the search results which I have reasoned... I must separate the search script from the insert script by including a form and submit button into the echo of the search script.

Comment: In this case, you can use ids of the rows you want to select. Store them as string with values separated by comma. Use them to fetch rows and my solution to insert these rows into another table.